# bc - command: not giving appropriate results

Tags: bc

I am trying to do simple calculation using bc command in linux. Once i want the value with all the decimal places. other time i want only the integer part

Want to get with full decimal places

```
$ echo "scale=10; ((900/1303) * 928)/600" | bc
1.0683039140
```

Now i want to get only the 1 (integer) part here omitiing the decimal part
SO i try

```
$ echo "scale=0; ((900/1303) * 928)/600" | bc
0
```

How its showing Zero. It should show 1 instead

Can someone help. I dont want to extract the interger part using awk or sed in this case

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
echo "scale=20; a=((900/1303) * 928)/600; scale=0; a/1" | bc
```

However, that's a truncate decimals, a result like `1.9999` will truncate to `1` also.

But that seems to be what you ask for.

---

> How its showing Zero. ...

Because `900/1303` (with zero decimals) becomes `0`. The `0` is carried to the end result. Maybe, if you reorder:

```
$ echo "( 900 * 928 / 1303 ) / 600" | bc
1
```

> ... It should show 1 instead

No, it should not, if intermediate divisions are carried out with zero decimals.

Comment: yes : ( 900 * 928 / 1303 ) / 600 will work.